# Duplicate entry of same record in database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have one form which takes lot of input data from users including image. Data inserts properly in table but it makes duplicate entry of same record in datatable. Please help I don't understand why it's taking duplicate entry of same data.

```
Private Sub save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles save.Click
        Dim name, businessCategory, subcategory, conPerson, website, email, phoneNo1, phoneNo2, mobileNumber, building, street, landpoint, area, city, stateName, zipCode, about, reg, foundationDate, founder, genBeds, icuBeds, mondayIn, mondayOut, tuesdayIn, tuesdayOut, wedIn, wedOut, thursdayIn, thursdayOut, fridayIn, fridayOut, saturdayIn, saturdayOut, sundayIn, sundayOut, visitIn, visitOut, fees, bestFor As String
        name = businessName.Text
        businessCategory = businessCat.Text
        subcategory = subCat.SelectedItem.ToString
        conPerson = contactPerson.Text
        website = websiteName.Text
        email = emailName.Text
        phoneNo1 = phone1.Text
        phoneNo2 = phone2.Text
        mobileNumber = mobile.Text
        building = buildingName.Text
        street = address.Text
        landpoint = landmark.Text
        area = areaName.Text
        city = suburb.Text
        stateName = state.Text
        zipCode = zip.Text
        about = overview.Text
        reg = regNo.Text
        foundationDate = foundation.Text
        founder = founderName.Text
        genBeds = GeneralBeds.Text
        icuBeds = ICU.Text
        mondayIn = mondayFrom.SelectedItem.ToString
        mondayOut = mondayTo.SelectedItem.ToString
        tuesdayIn = tuesdayFrom.SelectedItem.ToString
        tuesdayOut = tuesdayTo.SelectedItem.ToString
        wedIn = wedFrom.SelectedItem.ToString
        wedOut = wedTo.SelectedItem.ToString
        thursdayIn = thursdayFrom.SelectedItem.ToString
        thursdayOut = thursdayTo.SelectedItem.ToString
        fridayIn = fridayFrom.SelectedItem.ToString
        fridayOut = fridayTo.SelectedItem.ToString
        saturdayIn = saturdayFrom.SelectedItem.ToString
        saturdayOut = saturdayTo.SelectedItem.ToString
        sundayIn = sundayFrom.SelectedItem.ToString
        sundayOut = sundayTo.SelectedItem.ToString
        visitIn = visitFrom.SelectedItem.ToString
        visitOut = visitTo.SelectedItem.ToString
        fees = consultinfees.Text
        bestFor = bestknowFor.Text

        Try
            Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(profileDP.PostedFile.FileName)
            profileDP.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("assets/images/hospitals/" + filename))
            con.Open()

            Dim str1 As String = "INSERT INTO hospitals (`name`, `category`, `subcategory`, `contactPerson`, `websiteName`, `email`, `phone1`, `phone2`, `mobileNumber`, `buildingName`, `streetName`, `landmark`, `areaName`, `city`, `State`, `zipCode`, `thumbnail`, `consultancyFees`, `overview`, `Founder`, `establishment`, `registration`, `generalBed`, `icuBed`, `mondayFrom`, `mondayTo`, `tuesdayFrom`, `tuesdayTo`, `wednesdayFrom`, `wednesdayTo`, `thursdayFrom`, `thursdayTo`, `fridayFrom`, `fridayTo`, `saturdayFrom`, `saturdayTo`, `sundayFrom`, `sundayTo`, `visitFrom`, `visitTo`, `bestKnownFor`, `status`) values ('" + name + "', '" + businessCategory + "', '" + subcategory + "', '" + conPerson + "', '" + website + "', '" + email + "', '" + phoneNo1 + "', '" + phoneNo2 + "', '" + mobileNumber + "', '" + building + "', '" + street + "', '" + landpoint + "', '" + area + "', '" + city + "', '" + stateName + "', '" + zipCode + "', 'list-business/assets/images/hospitals/" + filename + "', '" + fees + "', '" + about + "', '" + founder + "', '" + foundationDate + "', '" + reg + "', '" + genBeds + "', '" + icuBeds + "', '" + mondayIn + "', '" + mondayOut + "', '" + tuesdayIn + "', '" + tuesdayOut + "', '" + wedIn + "', '" + wedOut + "', '" + thursdayIn + "', '" + thursdayOut + "', '" + fridayIn + "', '" + fridayOut + "', '" + saturdayIn + "', '" + saturdayOut + "', '" + sundayIn + "', '" + sundayOut + "', '" + visitIn + "', '" + visitOut + "', '" + bestFor + "', 'active' )"

            Dim str2 As MySqlDataReader
            Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim command As New MySqlCommand
            command.CommandText = str1
            command.Connection = con
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content_Type", "assets/images/hospitals/" + filename)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            str2 = command.ExecuteReader
            con.Close()
            Response.Write("Hospital added successfully!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure you do not call the same Sub save_Click twice somewhere in your code?

Comment: @FeliceM no it's once only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please pick only one between `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` or `str2 = command.ExecuteReader`.

> **ExecuteReader** used for getting the query results as a DataReader
> object. It is readonly forward only retrieval of records and it uses
> select command to read through the table from the first to the last.
>
> **ExecuteNonQuery** used for executing queries that does not return any
> data. It is used to execute the sql statements like update, insert,
> delete etc. ExecuteNonQuery executes the command and returns the
> number of rows affected. - from this [site](http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-executereader-executenonquery.htm)

I don't see why you should use **ExecuteReader** if you're just going to insert a record.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should use only `ExecuteNonQuery()` and only once if you are using INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE statements.

`ExecuteReader()` is for retrieving records from database table.

You are doing both and thats why its inserting twice.